# Line Projected - Linear discriminant analysis

Tags: algorithm, matlab, machine-learning, linear-algebra, linear-regression

I have two question. 
I have the attached code for linear discriminant analysis, that deals with two classes -each two features. It is the very basic one. 
However,

I don't know why my projected line is not the same as the tutorial. Please tell me where is the wrong implementation I did with respect to pdf attached.

http://research.cs.tamu.edu/prism/lectures/pr/pr_l10.pdf
http://www.di.univr.it/documenti/OccorrenzaIns/matdid/matdid437773.pdf

```
% Fisher's linear discriminant. 
% : xi is column vector of which element is test metric. 
% Therefore size of row is the number of test metrics. 
% Number of column is the number of data sets. 
% x1 = rand(2, 30) + 0.75.*ones(2,30); %[d1(:,c1) d1(:,c2)]';
% x2 = rand(2, 30) + 0.3 .*ones(2,30); %[d2(:,c1) d2(:,c2)]';
x1=[1 2;2 3;3 3;4 5;5 5]'  % the first class 5 observations
x2=[1 0;2 1;3 1;3 2;5 3]' % the second class 6 observations
m1 = mean(x1')'; 
m2 = mean(x2')'; 
m = m1 + m2; 
Sw1 = zeros(size(x1, 1), size(x1,1)); 
Sw2 = zeros(size(x1, 1), size(x1,1)); 
   for i = 1:size(x1,1)
       Sw1 =  Sw1 + (x1(:,i)-m1)*(x1(:,i)-m1)';
   end
  for i = 1:size(x2,1)
     Sw2 =  Sw2 + (x2(:,i)-m2)*(x2(:,i)-m2)';
  end

 Sw = Sw1 + Sw2; 
 w = Sw^(-1)*(m2-m1);
  scatter(x1(1,:), x1(2,:), 10, 'ro');
hold on;
scatter(x2(1,:), x2(2,:),10,'bo');
c = 0.5.*m; %Average mean.ie. m/2
quiver(c(1,1), c(2,1), 1, -w(1,1)/w(2,1));
quiver(c(1,1), c(2,1), -1, w(1,1)/w(2,1));
quiver(w(1,1),w(2,1), 0.5)
hold off;
figure; 
y1 = x1'*w; 
y2 = x2'*w; 
hist([y1 y2])
newy=w'*newp;
%newp is new point
diff1=abs(m1-newy);
diff2=abs(m2-newy);
if diff1 >=diff2
  %newp is included in class1
else

%newp is included in class2


 It has to be something similar to the following picture

[![smthg simialr to the following final results][3]][3]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to project the line between the two classes. Some solutions I saw, they used eigenvalue and vector to determine the projected line, and some others, don't need to go through determining eigenvalues.Why the rank of the co-variance matrix matter?

Eigenvalues are used for inverting the matrix, you are probably also using eigendecomposition inside `inv(sw)` call. This is not crucial to the method, you can invert your matrix in many ways.

> As consequences of question one, how can can I project the data of first class and second class. I mean how can I plot them.

The image provided is a bit missleading. Actually, the "line" (hyperplane) you are projecting onto should cross the origin (0,0) point. The fact they moved it away is just arbitrary decision - not supported by the method itself. Equation of your hyperplane is stored in your `v` vector, it is given in canonical form, thus

```
v_0 x + v_1 y = 0
```

is the line you are looking for. there are plenty ways of plotting lines in canonical form. One of which (assuming that it is not constant) is to express it in "high school format":

```
y = - v_0 / v_1 * x
```

which obviously works iff `v_1` is not 0, if it is, your line is simply X axis.

Comment: would you mind to tell me how is that? Can you plot the projected line and the project data from each class at that line. Thank you for declaring the idea of eigenvalue and vector, I think we can find the projected vector without going to eigenvalue and vector - as in the documentation.

Comment: I gave you equation of the line you want to plot. To plot (in 1D) projecteed data you just use dot product - as in your code.

Comment: since the vector from (v) is [-0.7936 0.8899]'.  I considered (x) as my original data of class 1, and I plot it as the following. **plot((0.793/0.889)*c1)**, am not sure why do I need dot product. I appreciate if you give more explanation, am still bit beginner.